# Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm creating my very first app with reactJS but I keep getting this error:

```
Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM element) or a ReactClass (for composite components). Check the render method of 'App'
```

I've already read a dozen of questions but none of them helped me get through this problem.
Here are my files:

my **app.js** file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { Header } from './components/common';
import { ChooseLevel } from './components/ChooseLevel';

class App extends Component {

  renderContent() {
    <ChooseLevel/>
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Header headerText="my app" />
        {this.renderContent()}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**ChooseLevel.js**:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';

class ChooseLevel extends Component {

  render() {
    var rows = [];

    for (var i=1; i <= 10; i++) {
        rows.push(
          <button style={styles.squareStyle}> 
            Level   
          </button>
        );
    }


    return (
      <div>
        {rows}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const styles = {
  squareStyle: {
    flex:0.3,
    height:60
  }
};

export default ChooseLevel;
```

Comment: What does `renderContent` even do? Return the component... also you must return the component when you do `rows` by foreaching or similar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are making a default export: `export default ChooseLevel;` but importing something else: `import { ChooseLevel } from './components/ChooseLevel';`

`import { ChooseLevel } from './components/ChooseLevel';` roughly converts to `const ChooseLevel = require('./components/ChooseLevel').ChooseLevel;`

To import the default export value you'll need to `import ChooseLevel from './components/Chooselevel';`

Take a look at http://es6-features.org/#Constants it explains every ES6 feature in detail.

Comment: great, upvote .. I need a consultation: as a top user in *react native* tag, do you think is learning it worthy?! Someone says it's perfect, someone else says that's a terrible idea .. So I'm confused, I want to make a mobile application (both for Android and iOS operation systems), well, is it possible to make professional apps by *react native*? Or react native just lets us to make beginner apps? Also what about the quality of apps which have been created by *react native*? thanks

Comment: I definitely shouldn't be in that list. I only played with it for a short while and don't have extensive experience with it. Nevertheless, the comments aren't the right place to seek this information, you and the community will benefit much more if this was a question of SO or programmers.SE. I'm sure there's been much prior discussion about this topic.